# COALESCE() to get Not null as well as NULL Values

Tags: mysql

I have my Mysql Query as :

```
select RecordID,ID,Name,Description,RecordDateTimeUTC,Location from
eemployee where RecordID like ? and(isNull(RecordDateTimeUTC) OR RecordDateTimeUTC=  CASE  WHEN COALESCE(?,'') = ''  THEN RecordDateTimeUTC  ELSE ?  END)........
```

Now my query There are lott of fields(? --> this is where i am putting my data for filter perpose) upon which user can query so i am using **coalesce** but the disadvantage of using **coalesce** is **it doesn't give me null values when i want to get all data present in employee table** , so to get null values i have used **isNull**  function.

Now i am testing the above query for two use cases

1-->User can pass percentage in RecordID:-In this case he should get all data either null as well as not null values :

```
    select RecordID,ID,Name,Description,RecordDateTimeUTC,Location from
        eemployee where RecordID like '%' 
and(isNull(RecordDateTimeUTC) OR RecordDateTimeUTC=  CASE  WHEN COALESCE('','') = ''  THEN RecordDateTimeUTC  ELSE ''  END)
```

2-->User can filter data based on RecordDateTimeUTC:- If user passes this parameter then he should get all not null data satisfying the above filteration.:-

```
select RecordID,ID,Name,Description,RecordDateTimeUTC,Location from
        eemployee where RecordID like '%' and(isNull(RecordDateTimeUTC) OR RecordDateTimeUTC=  CASE  WHEN COALESCE('2012-07-09 11:11:00','') = ''  THEN RecordDateTimeUTC  ELSE '2012-07-09 11:11:00'  END)
```

For the first use case it is working fine but for the second use case it is giving me filtered data as well as null Data

**So what should be my query so that both my use cases are supported by the above single query.
I am using MYSQl Query Browser to test my query**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to make parameters optional while using a single static SQL statement. In that case I would imagine you mean something like:

```
SELECT RecordID,ID,Name,Description,RecordDateTimeUTC,Location 
FROM eemployee 
WHERE (@RecordId IS NULL OR RecordID LIKE @RecordId)
AND (@RecordDateTimeUTC IS NULL OR RecordDateTimeUTC = @RecordDateTimeUTC)
```

If the parameter value is NULL, it will be omitted completely from the filter, otherwise the passed value will be used.

Note you can't use `?` here because of the need to re-use the parameter - unless you want to specify each parameter twice, that is. Specifying a name makes the query a lot more readable IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I have modified my query as per your suggestion and it looks like this SELECT RecordID,ID,Name,Description,RecordDateTimeUTC,Location
FROM eemployee
WHERE (@RecordId IS NULL OR RecordID LIKE '%')
AND (@RecordDateTimeUTC IS NULL OR RecordDateTimeUTC = '2012-07-09 11:11:00'). But for this i am getting Null values as well as values that contains '2012-07-09 11:11:00' for RecordDateTimeUTC

Comment: so you mean that i should passs data where you have mentioned @parameterName

Comment: Yes, or that you should define parameters and use them. (If you're going to replace the parameters with inline data you may as well just create the query dynamically anyway.)

Comment: can you provide me an example

Comment: I don't know how you're calling it, but either you want to specify values for `@RecordId` and/or `@RecordDateTimeUTC` parameters (same way you would add parameters normally if you were using `?`, but just make sure to give them names), or you would want to construct the SQL query based on the user's input.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33542/discussion-between-roy-and-lc)